# "<-" and associated values

Tags: haskell, monads

Say I've written the following amazin piece of code:

```
func = do
  a <- Just 5
  return a
```

It's pretty pointless, I know. Here, `a` is `5`, and `func` returns `Just 5`.

Now I rewrite my awesome (yet pointless) function:

```
func' = do
  a <- Nothing
  return a
```

This function returns `Nothing`, but what the heck is `a`? There's nothing to extract from a `Nothing` value, yet the program doesn't whine when I do something like this:

```
func'' = do
  a <- Nothing
  b <- Just 5
  return $ a+b
```

I just have a hard time seeing what actually happens. What is `a`? In other words: What does `<-` *actually* do? Saying it "extracts the value from right-side and binds it to the left-side" is obviously over-simplifying it. What is it I'm not getting?

Thanks :)

Comment: `<-` translates to `>>=`. In case of `Maybe` monad, if the first argument (i.e. the part right to `<-`) is `Nothing`, nothing else is evaluated and `>>=` just returns `Nothing`. So, to answer your question: the execution doesn't even _reach_ `a`.

Comment: Thinking of monads as containers, do-notation lets you assign labels to the values (if any) inside the monads, and then define functions to apply to those values.  But the extraction is an illusion - functions are applied _inside the monad_ (using `>>=`) because there is no general way to extract a value from a monad.  Notice how you end every do-block by putting the result _back into the monad_, often using `return`.  You never really had a variable `a` that was equal to 5.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Let's try and desugar the do-notation of that last example.

```
func'' = Nothing >>= (\a -> Just 5 >>= (\b -> return $ a+b))
```

Now, let's see how >>= is defined for Maybe. It's in the Prelude:

```
instance  Monad Maybe  where
    (Just x) >>= k   =  k x
    Nothing  >>= k   =  Nothing
    return           =  Just
    fail s           =  Nothing
```

So `Nothing >>= foo` is simply `Nothing`

Comment: Every foo <- bar follows the scheme bar >>= (\foo -> ...). Now you can also see why there must be an expression at the end of every do-block, or one of those (possibly nested) lambda expressions would have an empty function body. Perhaps this link will help: http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/monads.html#monads.do

Answer (score 6):

The answer lies in the definition of the `Monad` instance of `Maybe`:

```
instance Monad Maybe where
   (Just x) >>= k      = k x
   Nothing  >>= _      = Nothing
   (Just _) >>  k      = k
   Nothing  >>  _      = Nothing
   return              = Just
```

Your `func''` translates to:

```
Nothing >>= (\a -> (Just 5 >>= (\b -> return (a+b))))
```

From the definition of `(>>=)` you can see that the first `Nothing` is just threaded through to the result.

Answer (score 5):

Let's look at the definition of `Maybe` monad.

```
instance Monad Maybe where
  return = Just

  Just a  >>= f = f a
  Nothing >>= _ = Nothing
```

And desugar the `do`-notation in your function:

```
func' =
  Nothing >>= \a ->
  return a
```

The first argument to `>>=` is `Nothing` and from the definition above we can see that `>>=` just ignores the second argument. So we get:

```
func' = Nothing
```

Since the function `\a -> ...` is never called, `a` never gets assigned. So the answer is: `a` is not even reached.

---

As for desugaring `do`-notation, here's a quick sketch of how it's done (there's one simplification I've made - handling of `fail`, i.e. patterns that do not match):

```
do {a; rest} → a >> do rest
```

Note that `>>` is usually implemented in terms of `>>=` as `a >>= \_ -> do rest` (i.e. the second function just ignores the argument).

```
do {p <- a; rest} → a >>= \p -> do rest

do {let x = a; rest} → let x = a in do rest
```

And finally:

```
do {a} = a
```

Here's an example:

```
main = do
  name <- getLine
  let msg = "Hello " ++ name
  putStrLn msg
  putStrLn "Good bye!"
```

desugars to:

```
main =
  getLine >>= \name ->
  let msg = "Hello " ++ name in
  putStrLn msg >>
  putStrLn "Good bye!"
```

---

And to make it complete for those who are curious, here's the "right" translation of `do {p <- a; rest}` (taken directly from Haskell report):

```
do {pattern <- a; rest} → let ok pattern = do rest
                              ok _       = fail "error message"
                          in  a >>= ok
```

Answer (score 2):

`Nothing` isn't really "nothing", it's actually a possible value of something in the `Maybe` monad:

```
data Maybe t = Nothing | Just t
```

That is, if you have something of type `Maybe t` for some type `t`, it can have the value `Just x` (where `x` is anything of type `t`) *or* `Nothing`; in this sense `Maybe` just extends `t` to have one more possible value, `Nothing`. (It has other properties because it's a [monad](http://blog.sigfpe.com/2006/08/you-could-have-invented-monads-and.html), but that doesn't really concern us here, except for the syntactic sugar of `do` and `<-`.)

Answer (score 1):

Let's take your example:

```
func = do
  a <- Just 5
  return a
```

Just like in other programming languages you can break this into two pieces correspond to "what's been done up to now" and "what's is yet to be done". For example we can make the break between `Just 5` and

```
a <- ...
return a
```

In many popular programming languages you expect the `Just 5` to be stuffed into the variable `a` and the code would continue.

Haskell does something different. The "rest of the code" can be thought of as a function describing what you would do with `a` if you had a value to put in it. This function is then applied to `Just 5`. But it's not applied directly. It's applied using whatever definition of `>>=` applies, depending on the type of your expression. For `Maybe`, `>>=` is defined so that when dealing with `Just X`, the "rest of the code" function is applied to `X`. But it's also defined so that when dealing with `Nothing` the "rest of the code" function is simply ignored and `Nothing` is returned.

We can now interpret your other example

```
func'' = do
  a <- Nothing
  b <- Just 5
  return $ a+b
```

Break it into `Nothing` and:

```
  a <- ...
  b <- Just 5
  return $ a+b
```

As I say above, this block of code can be thought of a function applied to a possible value of `a`. But it's being used with `Nothing` and in this case `>>=` is defined to ignore the "rest of the code" and just return `Nothing`. And that's the result you got.